# Java apache poi error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown error type: -60

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I'm getting error `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown error type: -60` , in following code:

...

> evaluator.evaluateFormulaCell(c);

...

In excel file, all formulas works fine.

Stacktrace:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown error type: -60
at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.FormulaError.forInt(FormulaError.java:131)
at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell.setCellErrorValue(XSSFCell.java:611)
at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFFormulaEvaluator.setCellValue(XSSFFormulaEvaluator.java:203)
at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFFormulaEvaluator.evaluateFormulaCell(XSSFFormulaEvaluator.java:147)
```

...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to upgrade to a newer version of Apache POI.

Specifically, you need to be running POI 3.12 beta 1 or newer. If you look at the [changelog for Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/changes.html#3.12-beta1), you'll see that this bug was fixed between 3.11 final and 3.12 beta 1

Comment: Thank you very much. You saved my time. I used 3.6.final version. I changed to 3.11 version and it's working.